# JPA implicit flush at end of transaction not happening

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a method marked with org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

```
@Transactional
private void bob(String userName){
   User user = userRepo.getUser(userName);//autowired repo finds User domain Object
   user.setSomeDate(new Date());
}
```

then I call this method in for a loop

```
for(String userName: userNames ){
    System.outPrintln("something happens before we cal it again.");
    bob(userName);
}
```

The repo finds the users and there are no exceptions logged.

My understanding was that the dirty user object is a managed entity and would be saved when the transaction exits.

What I actually see is the user is flushed when the transactional method bob is rentered. So If the for-loop has 3 user names after execution I can go see the first 2 users get dates in the db and the third never gets flushed to db and remains dateless.
So my understanding appears to be wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method is private and by default Spring can only start a transaction in a public method that gets called from another class. You can get around this by using aspectJ.

From the spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> Method visibility and @Transactional
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
>   private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
>   no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
>   configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see
>   below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.

Comment: I tested it out and that resolved the issue. Thank you much I'll have to review this section of the docs.